# OnTouch listener with many ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, listener

in my current application using Android Studio I need to add some ImageViews dynamically into my FrameLayout. The user will select one or more images from gallery, I take the path of the image and put it in a arraylist, pass it to the activity that will use it and then create a drawable and set it to the imageview for each image selected.

That is working fine, but I need to move, rotate and resize them with onTouchListener. The problem is that I am just able to move the last ImageView added. It's like the last ImageView is the one focused and it's taking all the screen dimensions for the same ImageView and I cannot move the rest.
I tried doing something with "ids" as an idea I found looking for answers, but it stills always get the same id, from the last ImageView added.
[Here you can see both imageviews, but just the one on the right it's moving when I touch anywhere on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVWB4.png)

Here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
tools:context="com.example.anna.tfg3.WindowWorld"
android:foregroundGravity="bottom"></FrameLayout>
```

And my code:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < selectedList.size(); i++){ //List with selected image paths
        ImageView characterView = new ImageView(this);//Creating one imageview for each selected image
        characterView.setOnTouchListener(this); //I add the listener to each one
        Drawable charDrw = Drawable.createFromPath(selectedList.get(i));
        charDrw.createFromPath(selectedList.get(i)); //Create the drawable foreach image path selected
        characterView.setImageDrawable(charDrw); //I set the drawable for each image view
        characterView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        fl.addView(characterView); //Add it to the frame layout
    }
```

My onTouchListener:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    System.out.println("/777777777777777777777777"+v.getId());
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float dx = event.getX() - startPoint.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - startPoint.y;
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
                if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 3) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float tx = values[2];
                    float ty = values[5];
                    float sx = values[0];
                    float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}
```

Thank you very much!